# How to properly stop a "drawing" thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

A thread:

```
    public class DrawThread extends Thread {
    private RMapCanvas canvas;
    final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    final ArrayList<RGroupMapLayer> layers;

    public DrawThread(RMapCanvas aCanvas, ArrayList<RGroupMapLayer> arrayOfLayers)
    {
        canvas = aCanvas;
        layers = arrayOfLayers;
    }

    public void run() {
        activity.RaiseNotification(activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.loading).toString());
        for (RGroupMapLayer l : layers)
             {
                 l.validateAndRepairView(false, canvas.renderer, canvas.mapView);
                 l.render(canvas.renderer, canvas.mapView, canvas.mapEvent, 5000000, 5000000);
                 if (settings.getPositionFeature() != null)
                 {
                     RPointFeatureStyle positionStyle = new RPointFeatureStyle(RPointFeatureStyle.SIMPLE_POINT_STYLE_GPS);
                     positionStyle.render(settings.getPositionFeature(), renderer, mapView);
                 }
                 myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         canvas.RenderComplete(); 
                     }});
             }
     activity.statusMessage.cancel();
    }

    public synchronized void requestStop() {
        activity.statusMessage.cancel();
        this.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Calling the requestStop that interrupts a thread is not enough. The thread just keeps running. Can some one please update the code to show me the correct way of stopping this thread? And by the way ... the RenderComplete() methods updates the UI (witch is a problem in my case, because "old" threads keep updating the UI even if new one is starter and the old one interrupted).

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general interrupting or stoping threads by yourself is not recommended. Your thread should have a flag inside the run method. When the flag is `true` - the thread is running, when the flag is `false` - thread is also running, but now it doesn't do anything. The system will stop this thread when needed. Here's how it should look:

```
    public void run() {
        while (flag) {
        //do your work
        }
    }
```

And to "stop" the thread just use `flag = false;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not quiet the whole story, you'd need to make sure the 'flag' is volatile in this case. The preferred approach (mine) is to use the (internal) interrupt flag... so while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterruptted())

Comment: @Toby, It's not a good approach to interrupt the thread by yourself, nor stopping or pausing it.